# How to stop ActorSystem schedular which is scheduled with interval

Tags: akka, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, actorsystem

```
Public boolean checkStatus(){
    if(case){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.apply();
Cancellable result = system.scheduler.schedule(Duration.create(delay,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),Duration.create(interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)(checkStatus());
```

How i can stop scheduler when checkStatus case is true.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cancelling scheduled task you can use `scheduleOnce` method instead and then schedule it again if check is false or not if it's true. You will get the semantics you want that way.

Something along those lines:

```
public boolean checkStatus(){
    if(case){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public rescheduleIfFalse(ActorSystem system) {
    if(!checkStatus) {
        system.scheduleOnce(Duration.create(interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))(rescheduleIfFalse);
    }
}

final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.apply();
rescheduleIfFalse(system)
```